# GET API retrieving only 25 things

Tags: eclipse-ditto

http://(ditto-instance)/api/2/things?size=100

I tried with this, and it is not working. :(

In the database, I am able to retrieve 100 items.

Other API I tried: -
http://(ditto-instance)/api/2/things?page=1&count=50

Answer (score 1):

The `GET /api/2/things` endpoint does not support specifying a page size.
The `GET /api/2/search/things` API however does as documented, using the `option` param: https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/http-api-doc.html#/Things-Search/get_search_things

For example: `GET /api/2/search/things?option=size(100)`